# If I know the mean and median values of a distribution, can I determine the n'th percentile value?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

If I know the mean and median values of something (say, household net worth of a given city) and if I assume a standard distribution, how would I calculate what the n'th percentile value (say, the entry point for the top 1%) would be?

Comment: No, you'd need a lot more information.

Comment: Why would you want to use only those values?

Comment: Suppose you know the distribution is normally distributed, and $\mu=.5, \sigma=0.15.$ (Maybe it upper-class neighborhood, and millions of dollars.) Then you can use software or printed normal CDF tables to find 99th percentile. In R, code `mu = .5;  sg=.15; qnorm(.99, mu, sg)` returns $0.8489522.$ (That's. $\$0.849$ million) // For non-normal distributions, you have to be able to find $\mu,\sigma$ from known parameters.